# Strictly Monotone Surjective Function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I'm trying to show there does not exist a strictly increasing function:
$f: \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that is surjective.
I started by assuming that such a function exists. Then, this implies the function is continuous because it is strictly monotone with an interval as its image.  Now, I think I should somehow use that to contradict that there are enough values in $\mathbb{R}$ for each value in $\mathbb{Q}$, but I'm stuck. Hints?

Comment: $\Bbb Q$ is countable, $\Bbb R$ is not?

Comment: What do you understand "continuous" to mean when $\mathbb Q$ is involved? Topology with the rationals is *weird*.

Comment: I'm in a intro to real analysis class, so I'm only allowed to use basic definitions of continuity. I cannot use the cardinality of $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Note that the strictly increasing condition implies that the function is also injective

Comment: For the sake of the problem, is there a way to do it only using the  sequential or episolon-delta definition of continuity?

Comment: To sum up the comments above: You want to show there's no bijection $\mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. That shouldn't be too hard....

Comment: You seem to be trying to base an argument on connectedness. That is going to be more sophisticated than counting. You could try showing that the function $\mathbb Q \to \{0,1\}$ which sends everything less that $\sqrt 2$ to $0$ and everything greater than $\sqrt 2$ to $1$ can be combined with the inverse of the surjection to give a non-constant continuous map $\mathbb R \to \{0,1\}$ - but why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof that follows avoids using the fact that the cardinality of $\mathbb R$ is larger than the one of $\mathbb Q$.

Let $x_0\in \mathbb R\smallsetminus\mathbb Q$. Then as $f$ is (strictly) increasing, then the limit
$$
a=\lim_{x\to x_0^-}f(x),
$$
exists and it is a real number. In fact for every $x,y\in\mathbb Q$, with $x<x_0<y$,
$$
f(x)<a<f(y),
$$
as $f$ is strictly increasing.

This means that $a\not\in\mathrm{Ran}(f)$, and hence $f$ is not surjective.

**Note.** Let me explain better why for every $x,y\in\mathbb Q$, with $x<x_0<y$, we have that
$f(x)<a<f(y)$. As $x<x_0<y$, there are $x_1,y_1\in\mathbb Q$, such that $x<x_1<x_0<y_1<y$,
and since $f$ is strictly increasing, we have that
$$
f(x)<f(x_1)\le \lim_{z\to x_0^-}f(z)\le f(y_1)<f(y).
$$

Comment: The step where you note that $x_0 > x \in \mathbb Q$ implies $a > f(x)$ might need some unpacking, since it relies on some non-trivial properties of $\mathbb Q$  (specifically, that it is densely ordered); in particular, it would not hold if we replaced $\mathbb Q$ with $\mathbb Z$ (although the conclusion would obviously still be true).

Comment: is there a way to do this without using left/right limits?

Answer (score 3):

Let $p$ be an irrational number.  Show that the supremum of $f(x)$ for $x \in \mathbb Q$ with $x < p$ and the infimum of $f(x)$ for $x \in \mathbb Q$ with $x > p$ are be equal.  If this is $y$, then there is no rational $x$ with $f(x) = y$.